# Codeigniter Fails to Load Databases

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a set of databases that loaded fine yesterday. Today the site has started spewing php 500 errors whenever a database is called. It seems that codeigniter is failing to initiate the databases.php config file. I can connect to the database manually in mysqli_connect with the same info but it fails in codeigniter. How can I find the break point where the site is failing? Help is greatly appreciated, I'm 10 hours in and would really need some sleep.

Comment: [**Have you gone through the documentation?**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) <= on connecting.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly until 15 hours ago. It was working for 7+ years. It seems that codeigniter is failing and redirecting everything to error_php, but no amount of error_reporting will actually tell me what the error is.

Comment: *Hm...* - this sounds like maybe your PHP/SQL's been upgraded. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You may get a deprecation notice. You may need to upgrade your CI and/or change the settings in your config file.

Comment: Sometimes it keeps using dead connection which results in this error, try setting 'pconnect' to FALSE in your database.php file.